# Can't connect to my FTP server from another PC on the same network

Tags: iis, ftp, windows-10

I have setup an ftp server on Microsoft IIS on a windows 10 PC.

I have installed all the "World Wide Web Services"
Set up the ftp site with the PC's IP address and default port
Allowed specified users access to the site.
Created a rule in the firewall to ensure the port is not blocked.
Enabled the rules for the ftp port.

My problem is that while I can access the ftp server from the PC the server is running on, I can't access it from another PC that is on the same network. It doesn't give me an error, it just doesn't accept the credentials of the 2nd PC. I'm currently using the Windows login credentials to try and access the server. If that is the wrong credentials to use, where would I find the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

The connection is most probably blocked by the Windows firewall.

While the Windows firewall is automatically configured with rules for the ports 21, 990 and 1024-65535, when IIS FTP server is installed, the rules are not enabled initially.

To enable or change the rules, go to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules and locate three "FTP server" rules. If the rules are not enabled, click on Actions > Enable Rule.

For more information refer the [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server).